# isolating words using regex expression to text with separators specific

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I want to isolate ex. 3 word into long text

```
//more text
word word word (15:00 - - - 16:00 - - - 21:00)
//text ...
```

At this point i want to isolate times into parenthesis with a regex expression but i want to return in this format `15:00,16:00,21:00`

i have tried with 3 strings `'\).*' replace with ' '` `'.*\(' replace with ' '` and `'---' replace with ', '` the problem is, that there may be other brackets in the text, and then it won't work like here:

```
(word) word word (19:00 - - - 20:00 - - - 21:00) asd asd asd (text text)
```

I'm limited to replace-operations because yahoo pipes is not a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are limited to doing replace-operations? Because extraction would make more sense here.

The requirements and variables aren't very clear. Apparently (from the comments) there could be parentheses in front of and behind the one you wanna keep. Are there only ever 3 times? Or possibly 2 or 4?

This version assumes there are always 3 times in the parentheses you wanna keep, everything else in front of it gets captured.

```
^(?:[^(]|\((?!(?:\d{1,2}:\d{2}[\s-]*){3}))*\(
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bz2P4hxSARzDK74g)

So this regex select everything up to the times by saying *"match start of the line, then everything that isn't a `(` or a `(` that isn't followed by 3 time-notations with only whitespace (`\s`) and/or `-` between them"*

After that you can do:

```
'\).*' replace with ''
'[\s-]+' replace with ', '
```

Comment: no you're wrong.
`(asdas) word word word (19:00 ...) asd asd asd (text text)` in this case (with your suggestion) i obtain only the first.. (asdas)

Comment: You would obtain only the last `(text text)`. Sorry to say but I find "wrong" a very strong word here, I'm explicitly asking you whether the times-bracket pair is the last on on the line like it is in your example. It is not, OK, that's information you should've included in your question then. But I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: ok sorry, but when I say I need the format in brackets-containing times, it seems obvious that in the text, there may be other brackets as it is written in my original question '... the problem is, that there may be other brackets in the text, and then not work..'

Comment: ok exactly what I needed. As you suggested now, I first need to find times and then replace the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can only extract the strings that look like numbernumbercolumnnumbernumbernumber :

```
var result = str.match(/\b\d\d:\d\d\b/g);
```

result will be an array with all the matchs

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/oH7yI2/1)

Comment: \b : limit of a word , \d : any digit

Comment: I do not need javascript, I just need the string of logical reasoning, then,
Replace x with y.  thank you :D

Comment: if you first extract /\b\d\d:\d\d\b/g in array, then "implode" it with "," as a delimiter you get the string you need. Then you can replace the old string with the new one.
Or you may prefer to do everything with only one replacement ?

Comment: yahoo pipes is not a programming language. There are no hli array, I understand what you suggest but can not work I need a replace for the match

Comment: Then you can replace using back references , with a regexp like : ^(((?!\d\d:\d\d).)+(\d\d:\d\d))+((?<=\d\d:\d\d).)+$